# Upgrading Ruby from 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 on an Ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, ruby, apache, ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and I am using Apache 2.2.14, MySQL 5.1.61, Ruby 1.9.2 and Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and some other common Ruby gems (like DelayedJob 3.0.1, DelayedJobActiveRecord 0.3.2 Paperclip 2.7.0, WillPaginate 3.0.3, ...). I would like to upgrade Ruby to **1.9.3**.

My questions are:

1. Is there any known problem about upgrading Ruby from 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 and using packages mentioned above?
2. If (*1*) is no, what widgets I must use (or, better, which command lines I must run) in order to upgrade Ruby from 1.9.2 to 1.9.3?
3. Do you have some advice about the upgrading process?

Comment: Use [rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googled for Ruby 1.9.3 release notes and gone though couple of pages, based on that there are couple of improvements in

1. Garbage collection - [Lazy sweet GC](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/08/ruby193-gc)
2. Pathname, Date and couple of other libraries updated for performance, read more [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-1-9-3-preview-1-released-5229.html)

Looking at those things, we should not face any issues in migration your rails 3.2.2 project to ruby 1.9.2.

But for a safe journey I would strongly recommend you to test this in **development environment** with the help of **rvm**, so that if something goes wrong you can verify it against rails 1.9.2 version and update them.

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance is like lucapette said RVM. About the known problems, you need to check every gem you use if it's compatible with ruby 1.9.3 and check your code too.
You should not face any problems, since there are minor versions.